# Tomcat + jackson-databind => org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException

Tags: json, jackson, pom.xml, bcel

Having a primitive web application on Tomcat (9.0.63 or 10.1.16), try parsing the JSON and hence adding jackson-databind  to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.x.y</version>
</dependency>
```

where x.y could be 12.6, 16.0 etc.

and here we get:

> SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/serj/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.12.6/jackson-core-2.12.6.jar!/] for annotations
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
> ...

There are two explicitly basic technologies: Tomcat and Jackson. And such a strange result.
I tried to use various Tomcat and jackson-core versions

Has anyone encountered this?